# Implementing DotNetOpenAuth (oAuth2) for WCF (Rest Service) Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, wcf-rest

I have created a WCF API (Rest Services) and I would like to implement the protocol for authentication oAuth 2.

I know that this library DotNetOpenAuth is very useful for implement oAuth2 for WebApi but I havent seen any documentation or examples explaining how to implement DotNetOpenAuth (oAuth2) for a WCF project (Rest Service) (Framework 4.0)

Answer (score 0):

This this hope this may useful

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d8331c96-66f9-40ce-9d12-19e3d15f397d/wcf-rest-security-using-oauth-20?forum=wcf

Answer (score -1):

I'm was also looking for an example and found this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/372422/Secure-WCF-RESTful-service-using-OAUTH

Comment: Thanks for your answer user2616911, but that example is using oAuth version 1 not oAuth2